LTSpice: XOR with NAND gates
Make a two-input XOR gate:
$$
S1 = A \oplus B = A\cdot \overline{B} + \overline{}\cdot
$$
How can I achieve this on LTSpice using only NAND gates?

Hello and welcome.  You'll get the best out of EE.SE if you show what you've tried and what's going wrong, most especially for anything which looks like homework of any kind.  For your problem, can I suggest you read the NAND logic page of Wikipedia, and come back with a specific question if you're still having trouble.

There is nothing specific to LTSpice in this question.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/digital-electronics/implementation-of-xor-gate-from-nand-gate.htm

Hint: It only takes 4 gates

Go here.

@D.A.S., you can also use 5 gates

@SnappyRiffs  Higher Entropy solutions may be ignored

1: find a way to use a NAND gate as an inverter
2: use De Morgan's theorem repeatedly until you can construct all the circuit elements you need.
